# Using StyleSelector in UWP to Change ListViewItem Styles for Minesweeper Game

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, listviewitem

I am making a minesweeper clone for class. The basic game board is generated through code, but it is a series of `ListView` columns containing rows of `Tile` objects. This code generates the `ListViews` (it works fine):

```
  // Create as many lists as necessary to fill the board according to the size specified
  void createGameBoard(bool erase = true)
  {
     // Erase any previous game
     if(erase)
     {
        for(int i = mainGameBoard.Children.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
           mainGameBoard.Children.RemoveAt(i - 1);
        }
     }

     //        Main Game Board
     // column 0   column 1   column 2
     // tile 0,0   tile 1,0   tile 2,0
     // tile 0,1   tile 1,1   tile 2,1
     // tile 0,2   tile 1,2   tile 2,2
     // Create a new list view for each game board column
     for(uint col = 0; col < minesweepGame.Width; col++)
     {
        ListView column = new ListView();
        column.Name = col.ToString();
        column.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
        column.IsItemClickEnabled = true;
        column.ItemClick += Column_ItemClick;
        ///column.ItemContainerStyleSelector.SelectStyle()

        // Fill the column with tiles
        Tile[] columnTiles = new Tile[minesweepGame.Width];
        for(uint row = 0; row < minesweepGame.Width; row++)
        {
           columnTiles[row] = minesweepGame.TileList[col, row];
        }
        column.ItemsSource = columnTiles;

        // Append the newly created column to the main game board (in order of creation)
        mainGameBoard.Children.Add(column);
     }
  }
```

This results in a clean grid with animations.

[UWP Minesweeper using ListViews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yaeR.png)

I want to style items differently when they are revealed to the user (once it is clicked, a tile becomes darker and has numbers with different colours). So I looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.styleselector.selectstylecore#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_StyleSelector_SelectStyleCore_System_Object_Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyObject_) and [examples](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/10/wpf-style-selector-for-items-in.html), and created a `StyleSelector`:

```
   public class ColumnTileSelector : StyleSelector
   {
      private Style Tile0 = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
      private Style Tile1 = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
      private Style Tile2 = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
      private Style Tile3 = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
      private Style Tile4 = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));

      protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
      {
         Tile tile = (Tile)item;
         if(tile.IsShownGraphically)
         {
            switch(tile.AdjacentMines)
            {
               case 0:
                  Tile0.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Colors.Red));
                  return Tile0;
               case 1:
                  return Tile1;
               case 2:
                  return Tile2;
               case 3:
                  return Tile3;
               case 4:
                  return Tile4;
               default:
                  return Tile0;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            return Tile0;
         }
      }
   }
```

I also had previously created styles in the `XAML`:

```
   <!-- style the game grid tiles -->
   <Page.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="30"/>
         <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
         <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="30"/>
         <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="30"/>
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2, 2, 2, 2"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SlateGray"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBlack"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="Tile0">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="Tile1">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="Tile2">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="Tile3">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="Tile4">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange"/>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="mainGameBoard">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SlateGray"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      </Style>

      <local:ColumnTileSelector x:Key="tileColor"/>
   </Page.Resources>
```

However, nothing actually works.

1. How do I refer to styles from the `XAML` in the view's code?
2. More importantly, how do I specify that my `ListViews` should use the `ColumnTileSelector`?
3. In the code that generates the `ListViews`, I commented out `///column.ItemContainerStyleSelector.SelectStyle()`. Is it possible to specify my `ColumnTileSelector` class here? I'm confused.

The documentation is not clear on how things are connected together. I understand in principle, but none of the examples I see specify why things react as they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="Tile1">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"/>
         </Style>
         <support:ColumnStyleSelector x:Key="ColumnStyleSelector"    
              Tile1="{StaticResource Tile1}"/>
    </Page.Resources>
   <Grid>
    <ListView ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource ColumnStyleSelector}"/>
</Page>
```

1. Make the styles Tile1, Tile2, etc public properties of the ColumnStyleSelector
2. Put the Styles in the page Resources
3. Put the ColumnStyleSelector in the page Resources
4. Reference the Styles in the Resources in the ColumnStyleSelector attributes

Comment: Can you elaborate on points 3 and 4? Point 3 gives me an error: `'support' is an undeclared prefix.` The same happens when using `<local:... />`.

And for point 4, how to do this? `column.ItemContainerStyleSelector...`

Comment: I have `<local:ColumnStyleSelector x:Key="ColumnStyleSelector" Tile0="{StaticResource Tile0}".../>` and `column.ItemContainerStyleSelector = new ColumnStyleSelector();` However, properties `public Style Tile0 { get; set; }` do not seem to be referring to any XAML styles.

Comment: support is the namespace of the ColumnSelector class. as declared in the top of your xaml with an xmlns:support="using:Standard" ItemContainer.  Your column.ItemContainerStyle needs to be set to the style via a "{StaticResource ColumnStyleSelector}"  The resource on the page needs to be accessed by Page.Resouurces["Tile0"]

Comment: I don't remember whether I was able to use your answer at the time, but I'm accepting it to thank you for your work in providing it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Referring to style in the view code required a couple steps. First, create a page-type variable in the view: `static MainPage mainPage;` Second, initialize it in the page constructor: `mainPage = this;` Third, use the style in the view controller: `mainPage.Resources["TileExploded"] as Style;`
2. To specify which `StyleSelector` a list view must use programmatically, use this code: `column.ItemContainerStyleSelector = new ColumnStyleSelector();`, where `column` is a `ListView`.

As a result, it is possible to render`ListViewItem` elements with different styles using logic in the `StyleSelector`:

```
  // Selects what style applies to a list view item according to that item's properties when it is rendered
  public class ColumnStyleSelector : StyleSelector
  {
     protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
     {
        Tile tile = (Tile)item;

        if(tile.Type == (int)TileType.ExplodedMine)
        {
           return mainPage.Resources["TileExploded"] as Style;
        }
        else if(tile.IsRevealed == true && tile.IsShownGraphically == true)
        {
           switch(tile.AdjacentMines)
           {
              case 0:
                 return mainPage.Resources["Tile0"] as Style;
              case 1:
                 return mainPage.Resources["Tile1"] as Style;
              case 2:
                 return mainPage.Resources["Tile2"] as Style;
              case 3:
                 return mainPage.Resources["Tile3"] as Style;
              case 4:
                 return mainPage.Resources["Tile4"] as Style;
              default:
                 return mainPage.Resources["ListViewItem"] as Style;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           return mainPage.Resources["ListViewItem"] as Style;
        }
     }
  }
```

This, of course, can use any logic specific to the program, with the key statements being `return mainPage.Resources["XAML Resource Style Key Here"] as Style;`